# Redraw cursor at absolute top or bottom while keeping scrolloff

Tags: neovim, key-bindings, redraw

My goal is to remap `zt` and `zb` to set `scrolloff=0`, run `zt` or `zb`, then set `scrolloff` back to its original value. I like the context when scrolling, but when I hit one of these keys I really want the top at the top or the bottom at the bottom. I want to do something like this:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n", "zb", scroll_very_bottom, { desc = "better bottom" })
vim.keymap.set("n", "zt", scroll_very_top, { desc = "better top" })
```

---

To expand, what I'd really like is to have `zt` jump to the top of the screen but as my cursor gets further from the top `scrolloff` is updated to this distance with the maximum set to the previously set offset. So, say `scrolloff=3`.

1. `zt` puts current like at top of window.
2. `j` puts cursor on line 2 but leaves same line at top.
3. `j` puts cursor on line 3 but leaves same line at top.
4. `j` leaves cursor on line 3 but scroll window by one position.

Then scrolling is back to normal offset.

Comment: Put your cursor on the window's topmost line, then `:set scrolloff=3`. You'll notice that the window moves up three lines (or the line with your cursor moves down three lines). Even if your mapping would work, your function wouldn't.

Comment: use `:norm!` to prevent the keymapping recursively

Comment: Yeah, the correction I made in the answer does sort of work except for what you point out here. It will scroll to the screen absolute top or bottom as hoped, but the moment the cursor moves up or down, it jumps to the offset.

Comment: The poor man's solution would be to have a mapping to toggle `scrolloff`. In addition, you may or may not `:set scrolloff=0` when you do `zt` or `zb`. When did you intend to reset `scrolloff` anyway?

Comment: Yeah, simply mapping a toggle for `scrolloff` seems like the way to go. I'm not sure I follow your question. I intended to reset `scrolloff` directly after redrawing, but the really ideal solution would be to have `zt` redraw with cursor at top and with each line scrolled down increment `scrolloff` by 1, or something like that. So it goes to absolute top but gradually transitions back to the original `scrolloff` setting.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt that works great, but I still end up with the problem of immediately jumping to the offset. I'll update the question to expand on that.

Comment: You should be able to pretty easily adapt my solution here to work for `zt`/`zb` instead of mouse clicks and to renable `'scrolloff'` gradually instead of all-at-once: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19459/dont-use-scrolloff-5-for-mouse-clicks

Comment: Indeed Rich, that does look like it could do the trick. I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: @Rich: Thanks a ton. That worked like a champ. Answer updated with solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on great feedback and some [really good inspiration from Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42921/22390), I have put together a working solution for this and I love it.

```lua
local function scrolloff_should_reenable()
  if vim.w.orig_scrolloff == nil then return false end -- Nothing to do.
  if vim.fn.winheight(0) <= vim.w.orig_scrolloff then return true end -- Too small for override.
  return vim.w.orig_scrolloff < vim.fn.winline() and vim.fn.winline() < vim.fn.winheight(0) - vim.w.orig_scrolloff
end

local function scrolloff_add_autocmd()
  vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("h4s_scrolloff_enhanced", { clear = true })
  vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("CursorMoved", {
    group = "h4s_scrolloff_enhanced",
    callback = function()
      if scrolloff_should_reenable() then
        vim.opt.scrolloff = vim.w.orig_scrolloff
        vim.w.orig_scrolloff = nil
        return true -- Remove the autocmd.
      end
    end,
  })
end

local function scrolloff_disable()
  vim.w.orig_scrolloff = vim.opt.scrolloff:get()
  vim.opt.scrolloff = 0
  scrolloff_add_autocmd()
end

local function scroll_very_bottom()
  scrolloff_disable()
  vim.cmd(":norm! zb")
end

local function scroll_very_top()
  scrolloff_disable()
  vim.cmd(":norm! zt")
end

vim.keymap.set("n", "zb", scroll_very_bottom, { desc = "better bottom" })
vim.keymap.set("n", "zt", scroll_very_top, { desc = "better top" })
```